# How do I inspect the frame size of a UILabel at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I know how to debug and view values in log, the problem is one of my UILabels changes it's position depending on some logic in program. For example, if i have five UILabels as:

A

B

C

D

E

The other sequence is:

A

B

E

The issue is when i debug the frame values of label E appears same for both the sequence, which is definitely not the case. Is it possible to check the UILabel frame values at runtime, if the UILabel changes it's position. Thank you.

Comment: Of course you can: `CGRect frame = label.frame;`.  Where's your code?

Comment: Are you using Auto layout for the labels? I don't think there could be a way other than ViewDebugging if you are using Auto layouts.

Comment: Post the screenshot by turning ViewDebugging on.

Comment: There are actually many ways to do it - using `NSLog` at the right places, pausing the program execution with a break point and then using debugger comands to print it or using the view debugger.

Comment: Ok the actual problem was a condition in the later part of the program where if the sequence is of second type the frame of label E was set to the frame of label C, and hence the frame values would appear correct when i inspected it by setting a breakpoint, but would be displayed differently.

Comment: @BharatModi- Thanks for letting me know about view debugging.